# Bug in NSURLRequest or AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking, nsurlrequest

Not sure if this is a bug or I am missing something, most likely latter. My AFHTTPClient's base url is:

```
#define kBaseURL @"http://localhost:4567/api/"
self.client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kBaseURL]];
```

When I make a request to, for example `'/games'`, it actually sends the request to `http://localhost:4567/games` ignoring the API part.

Comment: The answer to "Is this a compiler/OS/library bug?" is always "No, it's your code."

Comment: @H2CO3...i know what you are saying, but always? There's a reason why  we have this https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ :)

Comment: @H2CO3 Really? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909324/nsjsonserialization-bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AFHTTPClient.h` file has tons of comments about exactly how to use `/`s to make sure everything fits together correctly. Check it out [on github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.h#L57-L63)

Comment: yea, it was a problem with '/' messing up. Basically, I had to remove trailing/leading '/'

Comment: @0xSina that's definitely bitten all of us.

Answer (score 2):

The ["baseURL" part of "`initWithBaseURL:`"](http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/initWithBaseURL%3a) bit should make it clear that it's only going to work with the scheme + host + port number part.

Once you've created your client, you can add parameters onto it's URL request via techniques like:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = 
    [self.client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/api/games" parameters:parameters];
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to simply define base url as #define kBaseURL @"http://localhost:4567/api" without the last slash