# Why does RKNSJSONSerialization crash on iOS 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm seeing a crash in RKNSJSONSerialization on iOS 6 only - not on iOS 7. I'm using RestKit 0.20.3 and it happens fairly consistently for me. Even when I make the same request and get the same response for iOS 6/7, it works fine on iOS 7 but crashes on iOS 6.

Here's the crash - it's an EXC_BAD_ACCESS: http://crashes.to/s/2610b639062

The relevant (crashing) line in RestKit's RKNSJSONSerialization is the return:

```
+ (id)objectFromData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error
{
    return [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:error];
}
```

So perhaps it's not RestKit at all - perhaps it's NSJSONSerialization.

I profiled the app with the Zombies tool and found this:

"An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'CFString (immutable)' object (zombie) at address: 0x16851250."

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Probably you have some sort of zombie problem.

Comment: Not sure this would help, since it's part of RestKit, but isn't it supposed to be: `return [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];`?

Comment: @btomw Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that's the issue (see updated code).

Comment: What is the JSON? Any unescaped Unicode characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved this. The issue was that my JSON had duplicate keys in it, and iOS 6 couldn't handle that. The solution is to remove the duplicate keys from the JSON before trying to parse it with NSJSONSerialization on iOS 6. Apparently Apple has resolved this issue on iOS 7, since it doesn't crash there.

Related: [NSJSONSerialization bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909324/nsjsonserialization-bug)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a typo.

Assuming there is an object called `error` of type `NSError`, the call `JSONObjectWithData:` takes a pointer to a pointer as the last argument, i.e. with `&`.

```
return [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the question with more code to show that RestKit is indeed passing in a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Certainly, if there is an error somewhere in the handling of `error` that would do it.